# java format string "%,d" and "%, d"

Tags: java, string-formatting

Why is

```
public static void main(String arr[]){  
  System.out.println("[" + String.format("%, d",1000000000) + "]");
}
```

Writing it as `[ 1,000,000,000]`, with a space in front of the number?

Also what does "%, d" mean as compared to "%,d" as a format specifier?

Comment: Added brackets to increase clarity - often useful in general print-'debugging' :}

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`"%, d"` means that you are printing 1 space, then an integer with comma(s) (`[ 1,000,000,000]`)

`"%,d"` means that you are printing an integer with comma(s) (`[1,000,000,000]`)

`"%d"` means that you are printing an integer without comma(s) (`[1000000000]`)

Answer (score 1):

When you run following line

```
// extra space in front with number formatted
System.out.println(String.format("%, d",1000000000));  
// number formatted with ,
System.out.println(String.format("%,d",1000000000));
// just number
System.out.println(String.format("%d",1000000000));

OUTPUT:

 1,000,000,000
1,000,000,000
1000000000
```